# What are current abiogenesis hypotheses for first food source?

Tags: microbiology, food, abiogenesis

What is the very first abiogenetic piece of reproducing life (small piece of RNA + ribosome that randomly occurred?) hypothesized to have used as an energy source? I'd be interested in sources to what experts in abiogenesis research have hypothesized on this subject, if any such researchers have spoken on the question.

Comment: In RNA world hypothesis, ribozyme is thought to play the role of reproducing molecule.  That may help you with more initial research, but I don't know the answer to your specific question.